# HTML/CSS Background image scale to 100%

Tags: html, css, background, scale

I have a large image that I want to set as the background for a 404 page. I want the image to be 100% wide every time someone loads the page, so that if their screen is smaller the image becomes smaller, if the screen is bigger, the image stretches. The height should change based on the width, it doesn't need to be the height of the page.

I don't have the code for this. Would it be better to do it in the HTML file or the CSS file?

Can you possible create a JSfiddle that could serve as an example? Thanks!

Comment: Answer posted, with working fiddle.

Comment: I will try them out tonight, and mark the best one as the answer.

Comment: please note that I had the wrong jsFiddle linked when you looked at it.

Comment: Okay. I will look at them all tonight when I am at the workstation with the project.

Comment: Someone down voted me. I wonder why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add this to your `CSS` code...

```
body {
    background-image:url('http://imageshack.com/scaled/large/268/gjb.png');
    background-size:100%,100%;
}
```

And then create a body...

```
<body>
<a href="http://dummycode.com">Dummy Code</a>
</body>
```

## [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TPUsQ/2)

Comment: and for a background image?

Comment: @Kryptos Posted, even has a fiddle.

Comment: So... this work with your image. But it doesn't work when I change the URL to my image `images/poseidon.jpg`

Comment: Try, `/images/poseido.jpg` see more on [Absolute Path](http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/a/absopath.htm)

Answer (score 2):

This is best left to CSS. Hard to tell without your code exactly, but the following should do what you want:

CSS

```
html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
body {
    width:100%; 
    height:100%;
}
#background {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url('http://www.placekitten.com/200/200');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="background">
    <div id="content">
        Hello world!
    </div>
</div>
```

***UPDATE***

See the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/DrydenLong/jywbd/

***UPDATE #2***

I'd like to point out, just in case those reading through don't see the comments on my post below, that while applying the `background-image` property directly to the `body` selector is simpler, it will also apply that same image to *every* page referencing that CSS file. Should you choose to use a single CSS file for your entire website, my code above will make it easier to have different background images for the 404 page and the rest of the site.

Comment: It has to be a background image because I add text overtop it.

Comment: @Kryptos Fiddle coming soon

Comment: Way more complicated than it has to be.

Comment: @DummyCode I'll agree that your answer below is simpler, but in this instance OP stated he wanted the background to be for a single page. I'm assuming he won't want the same background on the rest of his site, which is why my solution uses the `div` setup to keep his `body` and other selectors free for the primary background image. Should he use a single stylesheet that is...

Comment: @DrydenLong Ah... I had assumed he would be creating a different css file for the 404 page. +1 for a +1? ;)

Answer (score 1):

#### HTML Body content

```
none
```

#### CSS

```
html {
    background: url(http://www.astrophotography.co.nz/Lrg_Slides/20120619Milkyway.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

## [Demo(updated)](http://jsfiddle.net/BVAhr/2/)

Comment: Thats perfect, except for that fact that its not the background image... what would I do differently for a background image?

Comment: How would I use a file on my computer? the 'url' seems to be messing it up?

Comment: @Kryptos Just adapt the `url` part like-so: `background: url(myImageFolder/myImage.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;`. The link is **relative**.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are really looking for is a `background-attachment` property.

```
body { 
background-image:url('http://IMAGEURL');
background-attachment:fixed;
width: 100%;
}
```

You dont need to setup height property here, it's done for you automatically.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
body{background:url(http://www.astrophotography.co.nz/Lrg_Slides/20120619Milkyway.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat; background-size:100% auto;}
```